# Org-contacts and dired+

Tags: org-mode, emacs24, dired

I have a problem using org-contacts and dired+ in emacs 24.5.1. When org-contacts or dired+ active dired show only filenames without permissions, sizes, owners. When I comment org-contacts or dired+ in my .emacs file everything is fine. May be somebody knows why does it happen and what do I need to do to solve this problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Part of my .emacs file:

```
(require 'org-install)
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\.emacs.d\\org-contacts")
(require 'org-contacts)
(setq org-contacts-files '("M:\\Org\\contacts.org"))
(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)

(add-to-list 'load-path "C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\.emacs.d\\elpa\\dired+-20151110.921")
(require 'dired+)
```

Comment: I suggest you post the relevant part of your configuration file, so that people can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out that problem is solved then I toggle dired-hide-details-mode (M-x dired-hide-details-mode). And I need to do this every time I start dired+ even then global-dired-hide-details-mode is off (in .emacs).